# how to set environment variables for Ethereum indexer using Git bash?

Tags: web-crawler, blockchain, ethereum, git-bash, bitcoin

I am following this tutorial https://github.com/getamis/eth-indexer/blob/master/README.md and I have tried following code but when i used ls command it didnt showed the .env file. and on running docker-compose build command it also shows that MYSQL_DATA_PATH variable is not set. can any one help plz

```
    git config --global user.name "username"
    git config --global user.password "paswd"
    git clone https://github.com/username/eth-indexer.git
    cd eth-indexer
    touch .env
    echo "MYSQL_DATA_PATH=~/indexer-data/mysql" > .env
    echo "GETH_DATA_PATH=~/indexer-data/geth" > .env
    git add .env
    git add -f .env
    docker-compose build
```

Comment: `ls` will not show hidden files. Try `ls -lah`.

Comment: o yeah this command is showing file now.. one more thing you can tell me on running docker-compose build      command it also shows that MYSQL_DATA_PATH variable is not set. I have set env variable using this echo "MYSQL_DATA_PATH=~/indexer-data/mysql" > .env

Comment: Show your _docker-compose.yml_ file content

Comment: Thankyou ... problem was in .env file, i mistakenly wrote sql instead of mysql.. this problem is solved now  .. if you can recommend any solution for thishttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/58466856/runtimeerror-can-not-reuse-socket-after-connection-was-closed-using-docker