# RuntimeError: Can not reuse socket after connection was closed using docker

Tags: docker, sockets, go, ethereum, solidity

I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/getamis/eth-indexer/blob/master/README.md?fbclid=IwAR3g3SAjJ9ik_hHCFkol2k8YXo0GvBL15oSNC-hIU38_OZcKOT79x-RuiZg#usage) to run Ethereum crawler using Docker on window 10 using docker

after executing

```
$ MYSQL_DATA_PATH="$HOME/indexer-data/mysql" GETH_DATA_PATH="$HOME/indexer-data/geth"docker-compose up
```

in this line i got error:

```
409 Client Error: Conflict for url: http+docker://localnpipe/v1.25/containers/ee2b46142bae704d4963853e22a77ba896a8f841120ecf5ac97befca91847672/attach?logs=0&stdout=1&stderr=1&stream=1
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "threading.py", line 916, in
_bootstrap_inner   File "threading.py", line 864, in run   File "compose\cli\log_printer.py", line 233, in watch_events   File
"compose\container.py", line 215, in attach_log_stream   File
"compose\container.py", line 307, in attach   File
"site-packages\docker\utils\decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped   File
"site-packages\docker\api\container.py", line 61, in attach   File
"site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 400, in _read_from_socket  
File "site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 311, in
_get_raw_response_socket   File "site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 263, in _raise_for_status   File
"site-packages\docker\errors.py", line 19, in
create_api_error_from_http_exception   File
"site-packages\requests\models.py", line 880, in json   File
"site-packages\requests\models.py", line 828, in content   File
"site-packages\requests\models.py", line 750, in generate   File
"site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 496, in stream   File
"site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 444, in read   File
"http\client.py", line 449, in read   File "http\client.py", line 493,
in readinto   File "site-packages\docker\transport\npipesocket.py",
line 209, in readinto   File
"site-packages\docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 20, in wrapped  
RuntimeError: Can not reuse socket after connection was closed.
```

```
git config --global user.name "usrname"
git config --global user.password "paswd"
git clone https://github.com/usrame/eth-indexer.git
cd eth-indexer
touch .env
echo "MYSQL_DATA_PATH=~/indexer-data/mysql" > .env
echo "GETH_DATA_PATH=~/indexer-data/geth" > .env
git add -f .env
docker-compose build
mkdir -p ~/indexer-data/mysql ~/indexer-data/geth
# Create database sechema
MYSQL_DATA_PATH="$HOME/indexer-data/mysql" docker-compose up idx-database idx-migration
MYSQL_DATA_PATH="$HOME/indexer-data/mysql" GETH_DATA_PATH="$HOME/indexer-data/geth" docker-compose up
```

Comment: My first thought might be that you have multiple docker containers running - try `docker ps` on the command line and see if you have multiple instances of the same images running. You can stop them with `docker stop [container_id]`.

Comment: $ docker ps command shows this result
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

Comment: check this .. all containers which are running currently                                   docker container ls -a   result in this image.. image link is given                                                                                                https://ibb.co/GW63VNy

Comment: I'm also interested in having this answered.